# A property initializing Itself in a strange manner C#

Tags: c#

I have Two classes:

```
//The class with the Main method
Four tt = new();

class Four {
int a;

public Four() { Console.WriteLine("Inside the CONSTRUCTOR"); }

    public int PropA {
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("inside GET PropA");
            return a++;
        }
        set {
            Console.WriteLine("inside SSET PropA");
            if (value >= 0)
                a = value;
        }
    }

}
```

I have intentionally written "return a++" in side the get accessor in the PropA property, just to experiemnt with it(I know that It is not good practice).
I have noticed something(screenshot 1) strange. It appears that the int a becomes 1 when I create an object even though I did not call the PropA and even more that that, the console does not show that the get accessor was called.
Also when I change the "return a++;" in PropA to "return ++a;", Thedebugger shows that int a is 1 and PropA is one(screenshot 2)

Can you please tell me what exactly is called and when because this is really confusing?
*screenshot 1*
[image]

*screenshot 2*
[image]

Comment: `even though I did not call the PropA` - how do you think that debugger window displays the values of the properties?

Comment: You are looking for pre-increments (++a) and post-increment (a++).  Pre-increment will increment the value and then return it, post increment will return the value and then increment it.

Comment: Thank you, @canon and but my question was different.

Comment: Thank you @Neil, I think my question was different.

Comment: @GSerg, Could you please ellaborate?

Comment: The debugger window calls your property. To display its value to you.

Comment: @GSerg Oh, so you mean, The actual value of int a is not changed since I did not call the property?

Comment: The actual value of `a` has changed because the debugger called the property. The debugger shows you the changed value of `a`, too.

Comment: Okay, so It turns out that the debugger can do "changes". Wow that is interesting.

Comment: The debugger does not do changes. The debugger calls your property. Your property does the changes because you coded it that way. How can you call a method in order to get its return value without executing the code inside that method? If your `property get` deleted all files from your hard drive and returned the number of the files deleted, would you expect the debugger window to be able to display you the number of deleted files without deleting them?

Comment: Yeah understood. Used wrong words there. It is just pretty shocking that the a value of a property (field) can change because the debugger made a call .

Comment: Why does that shock you? The debugger is reporting the value of the property which requires running the code. The code is changing the field. *Ipso facto.*

Comment: And that is exactly why "It is not good practice" which you said above you understood! The debugger assumes you are reasonable and would not create [non-idempotent getters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495888/11683), so it's safe to call them. If that was not the case, there would be no way, in principle, for the debugger to show you the values of your properties. It would only be able to show the fields, which is done via reading a memory location. As opposed to calling a property getter, which is a method.

Comment: Okay, I have done some tests and I think get It now. The conclusin would be that doing this and checking the debugger is not a good idea sibce the debugger may show different values than the ctual values. Thank you very much @GSerg

Comment: @Erik_JI That would be a surprising conclusion. The debugger shows the actual values. The field `a` has the value of 1. It has it for real, and it will keep having it if you close the debugger window thus relieving your object from the debugger's supervision. And the property `PropA` returned its displayed value (0 or 1) for real too.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing different tests that why I said that. i am pretty sure I got the idea. Thank you very much.